# Cant understand fragment replace

Tags: android

I have trouble understanding in `FragmentTransaction.replace(id, fragment, 'string')` what does `.replace` actually

I read somewhere that it will replace the content of view id with fragment but in my

```
public class MainActivity extends 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) !=null) {
                    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
                        return ;
                    }
                    ArticleFragment first_fragment = new ArticleFragment();
                    HeadlineFragment second_fragment = new HeadlineFragment();
                    first_fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
                    second_fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
                    FragmentTransaction manager=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    manager.add(R.id.fragment_container, first_fragment,"first");
                    manager.add(R.id.fragment_container, second_fragment,"second");
                    manager.commit();
                }
                abc newFragment = new abc();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment,"second");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        }
```

it only replaces the first fragment that i added to `Transaction`, i.e. `first_fragment`.

And how do i replace a specific fragment?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with ***R.id.fragment_container***.  You should have a different first argument on the line below in order to replace a fragment that is not your "first" fragment:

```
manager.add(R.id.fragment_container, second_fragment,"second");
```

Comment: isn't the id ***R.id.fragment_container*** is there to specify where to add the fragment?